# Installing SSL on subdomain error- vhost would conflict with other HTTPS VirtualHosts within Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, subdomain, virtualhost, lets-encrypt

I have created a subdomain for a domain. I successfully added SSL to the domain but it gives the below error for the subdomain:

> selected vhost would conflict with other HTTPS VirtualHosts within Apache. Please select another vhost or add ServerNames to your configuration.

My DNS is correct. I can access the http version of the subdomain site without any problem.

I even added subdomain and IP to `/etc/hosts`

My goal is to add an SSL certificate to subdomain via `certbot --apache -d www.sub.example.com -d sub.example.com`

I have five more domain on my virtual host and I created SSL certificates for all of them without any problem.

I have tried to change sub directory address...change NameAlias...

I got the below error:

> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
>      entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
>      contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
>      your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
>      firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
>      client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
>      that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.

Comment: My sub.example.com.conf on both sites-available and enabled is as below
`<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.sub.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/sub.example.com
        ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/sub.example.com/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/sub.example.com/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: My example.com.conf on both sites-available and enabled is as below

`<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.example.com
 ServerAlias example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs
 ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/example.com/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/example.com/requests.log combined
   </VirtualHost>

Comment: #below is the rest of example.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.sub.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/sub.example.com
        ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/sub.example.com/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/sub.example.com/requests.log combined
   </VirtualHost>

Comment: You need to put all of this additional information into your question, not as comments. Please remember to format them correctly.

Comment: These need to be accessible from the outside so adding them to `/etc/hosts` won't help. Obviously a DNS issue. How long ago did you add them? You have to wait for the NS information to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. I added subdomain to ServerAlias and certbot --apache -d sub.example.com works. However, someone suggested me to add AAAA record for my subdomain and try certbot --apache -d www.sub.example.com again.